# How can I center views on the screen instead of the surrounding view containers?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have gone through countless tutorials about SwiftUI in general and alignments in view containers but none of them where able to answer my question.

I would like to create a List of pingpong matches looking like this:
[image]

The "-"-characters of the scores are supposed to be in the middle of the screen no matter where the other Texts are and how long they are. But all I got to work so far looks like this:
[image]
My Code looks like this:

```
struct MatchView: View {

    @ObservedObject var match: Match

    init(match: Match){
        self.match = match
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text(self.match.player1.name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.match.objectWillChange.send()
                    self.match.makePoint(player: 1)
                    print("1: " + String(self.match.currentSet.pointsPlayer1))
                }
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    self.match.objectWillChange.send()
                    self.match.subPoint(player: 1)
                    print("1: " + String(self.match.currentSet.pointsPlayer1))

                }

                if self.match.setsWon1 == 2{
                    Text("")
                }else{
                    Text("")
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Text(String(self.match.setsWon1))
                    Text(" - ")
                    Text(String(self.match.setsWon2))
                }
                Spacer()
                if self.match.setsWon2 == 2{
                    Text("")
                }else{
                    Text("")
                }
                Text(self.match.player2.name)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.match.objectWillChange.send()
                    self.match.makePoint(player: 2)
                    print("2: " + String(self.match.currentSet.pointsPlayer2))
                }
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    self.match.objectWillChange.send()
                    self.match.subPoint(player: 2)
                    print("2: " + String(self.match.currentSet.pointsPlayer2))

                }


            }
            ForEach(self.match.sets){set in
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        Text(String(set.pointsPlayer1))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        Text(" - ")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        Text(String(set.pointsPlayer2))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting your view in three columns with a fixed width of 30% screen's width. First you should wrap your parent view with a [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader) this will give you the sizes of the screen, then pass the width to the child view, set a frame to each HStack that will represent your columns, and finally set proportional the width. Here is an example based on your code.

**Child View**

```
struct MatchSet: Hashable {
    var pointsPlayer1: Int
    var pointsPlayer2: Int
}

struct Match: Hashable {
    var sets: [MatchSet]
    var currentSet: MatchSet
    var player1Name: String
    var player2Name: String
    var setsWon1: Int
    var setsWon2: Int
}

struct MatchView: View {
    let parentViewWidth: CGFloat
    var match: Match

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                HStack{
                    Text(self.match.player1Name).lineLimit(1)
                    if self.match.setsWon1 == 2{
                        Text("")
                    }else{
                        Text("")
                    }
                }.frame(width: parentViewWidth * 0.3)

                HStack{
                    Text(String(self.match.setsWon1))
                    Text(" - ")
                    Text(String(self.match.setsWon2))
                }.frame(width: parentViewWidth * 0.3)

                HStack {
                    if self.match.setsWon2 == 2{
                        Text("")
                    }else{
                        Text("")
                    }
                    Text(self.match.player2Name).lineLimit(1)
                }.frame(width: parentViewWidth * 0.3)
            }

            ForEach(self.match.sets, id: \.self){set in
                HStack{
                    Text(String(set.pointsPlayer1))
                    Text(" - ")
                    Text(String(set.pointsPlayer2))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent View**

```
//...    
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { metrics in
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.matches, id: \.self) { match in
                MatchView(parentViewWidth: metrics.size.width, match: match)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 * 0.3 = 0.9 which wastes screen real estate. Wouldn’t it be better to divide `width` by 3?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried that at first but the view gets out of the screen: https://imgur.com/a/lfpu4ww @Magnas

Comment: Hi @zgluis, Thx a lot for your help. With some small modifications your suggestion worked. But it seems to create another problem. Now the height of the list cell seems to be fixed. So if a match has multiple sets the top and the bottom of the view moves out of the visible part of the cell. Do you by any chance have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Yes, instead of wrap MatchView with GeometryReader wrap the parent view, I will edit the answer. @Hannes

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using the following pattern (tested with Xcode 11.3 / iOS 13.3)

[image: demo]

```
ZStack {                   // center alignment for content by default
    HStack {
        Text("Left Text")
        Spacer()               // << pushes texts to edges
        Text("Right Text")
    }
    Text("Centerred Text")
}
```